# Can a Lenovo T530 boot from an USB drive?

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo-laptop

Does the Lenovo T530 laptop support booting from an USB drive?

Comment: Is there any reason to assume the contrary? Why would it not be able to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Source: I own one.

Basically any modern computer boots from USB.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the Lenovo Support site:

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028698

They are bootable usb tools that can be used with there systems. It lists the ThinkPad T530 as a supported system. To double check go into your BIOS and check to make sure there is an option for USB.